# Landsat 5 last image in 2011?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-5, earth-explorer

I tried finding latest images of Landsat 5 in Earth Explorer of path 202 row 24 and the latest result is from 10/2011.

Isn't Landsat 5 operational or at least been around after 2011?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_5 says last image was Jan 13, and that images were suspended from Nov 11 for 90 days. Perhaps there wasn't any collection for your particular location in the little remaining life.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, still where are images from 2012 then?

Comment: The same source says "Near the end of its mission, Landsat 5's use was hampered by equipment failures". If there are no images in the catalogue it may mean that they do not exist.

Comment: Yes probably the case, or maybe it's not released to the public yet as pretty sure my search criteria is OK on Earth Explorer. Wikipedia's sources are all broken links for that article not very reliable...

Comment: There are some images from 2012, but coverage is very patchy (I see content in path 31 and 39). You're on the trailing edge of life, and quality probably wasn't the greatest in any case. Reasonably authoritative history at http://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/landsat-5/ (with some obvious bias against commercialisation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [USGS](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/TM):

> The Landsat Thematic Mapper (TM) sensor was carried onboard Landsats 4
>   and 5 from July 1982 to May 2012 with a 16-day repeat cycle,
>   referenced to the Worldwide Reference System-2. Very few images were
>   acquired from November 2011 to May 2012. The satellite began
>   decommissioning activities in January 2013.